# Custom Sharepoint 2013 service Dependency Injection

Tags: 2013, service, isapi

I've created a custom service in the ISAPI folder. But the constructor of the service contains an interface (Dependency Injection) as parameter. How can I make the service initialize with the correct class?

If possible, I would like to use `SimpleInjector` as IoC container.
Do I need to create a `ServiceHostFactory` in this case?

Any examples for this?

SP2013 on premise environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody knew the answer (or wouldn't share it with us), I went on a little investigation adventure and wrote a blogpost about it:

http://www.rubenherman.be/ioc-sp2013/

Comment: Link has been deleted :-( pls provide answer in stackoverflow